# Monotouch: Is it possible to present DialogViewController inside of a usual UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need to create login screen for iPad and I need my login inputs to be fixed width.
Is it possible to fix length of DialogViewController elements or create a layout with UIView element and nest DialogViewController in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drunkcamel,  you can set frame size of view for dialog and add dialog as subview to other view

```
public class InlineDialogViewController : UIViewController
{
    public InlineDialogViewController()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var dialog = new DialogViewController(null);

        dialog.View.Frame = new  RectangleF(0,0,100,100); // set custom dialog size

        View.AddSubview(dialog.view);
    }
}
```